# The 'ArrayIndex' LINQ expression node type is not supported by LINQ to Entities - using interface & ReportViewer

Tags: interface, linq-to-entities, reportviewer

a quick question really.
I'm struggling to implement Linq2Entities statement that could take more than one value for a particular "field". I'm passing a number of strings to the `getClientsProjected()` I can easily compare single value. But I've got on my page multiple dropdown and out of that I get string separated with coma I then later use to split it to `string[]` e.g. `__ACCOUNT_SITE = "1234,5678"` (see the code below) I've tried for/foreach/contains none of which worked...

```or-tag-here
public IQueryable<ClientViewModel> getClientsProjected(string __ACCOUNT_SITE, string __ACCOUNT)
{
    var projectedClients = from c in getClosedSRs()
                           select new ClientViewModel
                           {
                               _ACCOUNT_ID_CSR = c.ACCOUNT_ID_CSR,
                               _ACCOUNT = c.ACCOUNT,
                               _ACCOUNT_FAMILY = c.ACCOUNT_FAMILY,
                               ...
                               ...
                               _ACCOUNT_SITE = c.ACCOUNT_SITE
                           };

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(__ACCOUNT) != true && __ACCOUNT != "ALL")
    {
        //this works fine as an __ACCOUNT is of a single value
        projectedClients = projectedClients.Where(c => c._ACCOUNT == __ACCOUNT);
    }

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(__ACCOUNT_SITE) != true && __ACCOUNT_SITE != "ALL")
    {
        String[] splitSites = __ACCOUNT_SITE.Split(',');
        //????????????????????????????????????????????????
    }
    return projectedClients;
}
```

Now, to most of you this will make complete sense. I've read many articles but did not find a proper answer. I however can't use Linq2SQL as already built my entire site using L2E, interface and ReportViewer.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to filter projectedClients based on the values in splitSites, then use:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(__ACCOUNT_SITE) != true && __ACCOUNT_SITE != "ALL")
{
    String[] splitSites = __ACCOUNT_SITE.Split(',');
    projectedClients = projectedClients.Where(x => splitSites.Contains(x._ACCOUNT);
}
```

Comment: I did try this and got the following error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String], System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: You need to create a List<string> first.  Try to use: `List<string> splitSites = __ACCOUNT_SITE.Split(',').ToList();` in place of the array.

Comment: I added the ToList(); above to convert to a list.

Comment: Thanks Leons, It worked without splitting it: " projectedClients = projectedCLients. Where(c => __ACCOUNT_SITE.Contains(c._ACCOUNT_SITE)):  " Before I was doing it other way around, so I owe you big time!